# Though I send response from HttpHead method , client says "Could not get any response"

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, winforms, asp.net-web-api

I have a `HttpGet` method in a controller in a windows application project.
I need to return `Headers` from it, so method's return type is `HttpResponsemessage`. but not able to get any response from that method.

I have one `HttpGet` method in a controller in a windows application, it is behaving like a Head method, as I am changing Head request type to `HttpGet` using Handler ([ref](https://www.strathweb.com/2013/03/adding-http-head-support-to-asp-net-web-api/)).

```
    [HttpGet]
    public HttpResponseMessage Get(HttpRequestMessage msg)
    {
        HttpResponseMessage res = new HttpResponseMessage
        {
            Content = new StringContent("", Encoding.UTF8, "text/plain")
        };

        res.Headers.Add("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
        res.Headers.Add("Keep-Alive", "timeout = 1000 max = 100");
        return res;
        //return "Hi";
    }
```

In wireshark when I see request and response,
I don't see any response , also tried by sending request from postman, 
I am not able to get any response.

but when I change return type to string in gives status code `200 ok` in response.

```
    [HttpGet]
    public string Get(HttpRequestMessage msg)
    {
        return "Hi";
    }
```

But I want to return headers not content. 
How can I achieve it? 
Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: In your code you are sending empty value in `HttpResponseMessage res = new HttpResponseMessage
        {
            Content = new StringContent("Add your string message", Encoding.UTF8, "text/plain")
        };` then you will get response. Checked your code API in Postman it returns `200 Ok` as response code

Comment: you can also use `IHttpActionResult` and send a response like `return Content(HttpStatusCode.OK, "Your String");`

Comment: @SH7, but I want to also return headers ,Connection - "Keep-Alive", and Keep-Alive - "timeout = 1000 max = 100, how can I achieve it?